# Regex Replace Match Found in String

Tags: c#, regex

I am using a Regex to find a pattern within a string.  After I find a match I would then like to remove it from the existing string.

For example:

```
starting string ex: "Billed Hours (.5);" 
converted string: "Billed Hours"
```

The regex pattern I am using is  @"([a-z.]+);$" - Not sure if this is correct, I want to check that only whole numbers or decimals are within the parentheses. If the pattern matches then remove parentheses, the value inside as well as the following semi-colon.

This is what I have so far:

```
string testString = "Billed Hours (.5);"
testString = Regex.Replace(testString, @"\([a-z.]+\);$", "");
```

This is in C#.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're currently missing digits.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the regex:

```
@"\s+\([^)]+\);$"
```

And replace by nothing.

The `\s+` is to avoid having to trim spaces and `[^)]+` matches any character except closing paren.

Comment: Jerry so you are saying I should try this? string newString = Regex.Replace(testString, @"\s+\([^)]+\);$", ""); I still get nothing replaced and the same original string.

Comment: @Aaron Uh, that's not the regex I suggested... I meant this: `string newString = Regex.Replace(testString, @"\s+\([^)]+\);$", "");`

Comment: Posted the wrong Regex in my reply.  Everything is working thanks Jerry.

Answer (score 1):

Consider...

```
string testString= Regex.Replace(testString, @"\(\d*\.?\d*]*\);$", "");
```

Comment: The string is identical and not removing the parentheses, value within or the semi-colon. Wondering what I'm doing wrong....